# How to show 5 min unstoppable timer in flutter app?

Tags: asynchronous, timer, dart, flutter

I want to show a 5 min timer in my app which does't stop even when the app is closed and show the time left in mm:ss format. How can I show the time?

Comment: You'll need a persistent storage then, take a look at this plugin for instance: https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/persistence/key-value and store the initial time and the value for the timer.

Comment: Persisting isn't my concern, how do I show the time left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very very rudimentary example of how such a timer could work which persistently stores the target time:

```
class TimerApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TimerAppState createState() => _TimerAppState();
}

class _TimerAppState extends State<TimerApp> {
  SharedPreferences prefs;
  DateTime target;
  String timeLeft = "";
  bool running = true;

  @override
  void initState() async {
    super.initState();

    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    target = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(prefs.getInt('target'));

    if (target == null || target < DateTime.now()) {
      target = DateTime.now().add(Duration(minutes: 5));
    }
    executeTimer();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    prefs.setInt('target', target.millisecondsSinceEpoch);
    running = false;
    super.dispose();
  }

  void executeTimer() async {
    while (running) {
      setState(() {
        timeLeft = DateTime.now().isAfter(target)
          ? '5 min expired. Restart app to reset.'
          : target.difference(DateTime.now()).toString();
      });
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(timeLeft),
    );
  }
}
```

Note that this example is not very fleshed out; several features are missing and using a `while (running)` loop is probably not the most elegant solution.

Here are some more resources you could have a look at:

- The [shared_preferences package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences) for saving state persistently.
- This [Fluttery egg timer tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svxUUz5mi9s) that uses a more sophisticated form of state management.

Comment: This will definitely help! Thanks a lot :) I will try this out.